# C++ Data structure (buffer) representing 2D vertices, line segments and triangles hierarchically

Tags: c++, algorithm, buffer

I have written a templated class representing a buffer of elements. Now, I have to insert in this buffer 2D vertices (this is easy and done). Now I want to create a buffer, representing line segments, that vertices are based on the 2D buffer vertices. For example in my "vertex buffer" I have inserted 2 vertices. Then I create a "line segment buffer", and insert one line segment. This line segment ends are represented by the 2 vertices in the "vertex buffer". Now, if I change coordinates of one vertex inside the "vertices buffer", the line segment coordinates must change too. 
Its some king of hierarchical structure. 2D vertices <= line segment <= triangle.

Mu buffer class looks like:

```
template <class T>
class Buffer
{
public:
    Buffer(Buffer& buffer);
    Buffer(size_t initialBufferSize = 1);
    ~Buffer();

    Buffer& operator=(const Buffer& buffer);
    T& Buffer::operator[](const int nIndex);

    void insertElement(T element);
    void deleteElement(size_t index);
    size_t count();

private:
    T* elements_;
    size_t elementsCount_;
    size_t bufferSize_;
    void resizeBuffer(size_t newBufferSize);
};
```

The deleteElement method:

```
template <class T>
void Buffer<T>::deleteElement(size_t index)
{
    if (index >= elementsCount_)
        throw "No element at specified index";
    if (elementsCount_-index-1 > 0)
        memcpy(elements_+index, elements_+index+1, (elementsCount_-index-1)*sizeof(T));
    elementsCount_--;
}
```

The problem is when I delete a vertex from the "vertex buffer". The line segment's pointer to the deleted vertex will be invalid. How can I handle these kind of situations?

Basically, I have a buffer of vertices, and want to create line segments and triangles based on the vertices that I got.

PS: The line segment struct looks like this:

```
struct LineSegment {
Buffer<Vertex>* buffer;
size_t indexOfVertexA, indexOfVertexB;
//Now if I want to access the lineSegment vertices, I use **lineSegment.buffer[indexOfVertexA]**
}
```

Comment: Ever thought about using `std::vector<>` ? :)

Comment: Yes, but it's a homework, must use my own class. And with std::vector<> the problem, that I've mentioned above, persists.

Comment: Your 2D vertex class need to know the list of segments

Comment: @Mayhem50 You mean, that when a vertex gets deleted from the buffer, it must delete all the line segments in the line segment buffer that used him? Its a two way dependency (a line segment depends on two vertices, but these two vertices have a list of line segments, that use them). Is it a right concept?

Comment: It sounds like it's awful but in meshes structure it's done like this.

Comment: Ok, I've decided to deny removing vertices from the buffer when they are used by segments. Now how can I point from the LineSegment structure to the vertices in buffer? By index is a bad idea, because when removing a vertex, indexes changes.

Answer (score 0):

you should look at std::shared_ptr : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/shared_ptr/

You should organize the deletion with your data structure conveniance.

Delete Vertices --> which segments concerned --> which triangles. And remove all references

Comment: I suspect using a `shared_ptr<>` will cause more problems as vertices tend to need to be in buffers to throw down the pipeline whereas with shared pointers, this is not possible.

Comment: If you use shared_ptr for memory management, you can use the pointer holded to work with